# How to add OOV terms in a word embeddings model

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim

I am using a word embeddings model (FastText via Gensim library) to expand the terms of a search. 
So, basically if the user write "operating system" my goal is to expand that term with very similar terms like "os", "windows", "ubuntu", "software" and so on.

The model works very well but now the time has come to improve the model with "external information", with "external information" i mean OOV (out-of-vocabulary) terms OR terms that do not have good context.

Following the example i wrote above when the user writes **operating system** i would like to expand the query with the "general" terms:

Terms built in the FastText model:

- windows
- ubuntu
- software

**AND**

terms that represent (organizations/companies) like "Microsoft", "Apple" so the complete query will be:

- **term**: operating system
- **query**: operating system, os, software, windows, ios, Microsoft, Apple

My problem is that i DO NOT have companies inside the corpus OR, if present, i do not have to much context to "link" Microsoft to "operating system".

For example if i extract a piece inside the corpus i can read "... i have started working at Microsoft in November 2000 with my friend John ..." so, as you can see, i cannot contextualize "Microsoft" word because i do not have good context, indeed.

A small recap:

1. I have a corpus where the companies (terms) have poor context
2. I have a big database with companies and the description of what they do.

What i need to do:

I would like to include the companies in my FastText model and set "manually" their words context/cloud of related terms.

Ideas?

Comment: You can't, First you need to understand the purpose for using the word embeddings either word2vec or fast text library, it is used for finding the word vectors as per the context by the surrounded words.

Comment: @min2bro i know but i must put the companies in the context too... so, should i manually add them in the corpus? and the train the model again ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way how to do it. [The FastText algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04606.pdf) uses character-level information, so it can infer embeddings for unseen words. This is what the FastText paper says about representing the words:

[image]

However, this makes sense only in the case of words where you can infer what they mean from knowing the parts. E.g., if you had a reliable embedding for "walk", but not for "walking" and there were plenty of words ending with "ing", FastText would be able to infer the embedding. But this obviously cannot work with words like "Microsoft".

The best thing you can do is train your embeddings on data that contain the words you want the model work with of genre as similar as possible. If your text is in English, tt should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of models need numerous, varied usage examples to place a token in a relatively good place, at meaningful distances/directions from other related tokens. If you don't have such examples, or your examples are few/poor, there's little way the algorithm can help.

If you somehow know, *a priori*, that `'microsoft'` should appear in some particular vector coordinates, then sure, you could patch the model to include that word->vector mapping. (Though, such model classes often *don't* include convenient methods for such incremental additions, because it's expected words are trained in bulk from corpuses, not dictated individually.)

But if you don't have example text for some range of tokens, like company names, you probably don't have independent ideas of where those tokens should be, either.

Really, you need to find adequate training data. And then, assuming you want the vectors for these new terms to be in the "same space" and comparable to your existing word-vectors, combine that with your prior data, and training all the data together into one combined model. (And further, for an algorithm like FastText to synthesize reasonable guess-vectors for never-before-seen OOV words, it needs lots of examples of words which have overlapping meanings and overlapping character-n-gram fragments.)

Expanding your corpus to have better training data for, say, 100 target organization names might be as simple as scraping sentences/paragraphs including those names from available sources, like Wikipedia or the web.

By gathering dozens (or even better hundreds or thousands) of independent examples of the organization names in real language contexts, and because those contexts include many mutually-shared other words, or names of yet other related organizations, you'd be able induce reasonable vectors for those terms, and related terms.